# How would I send information from one screen to another without navigating to the other screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am fairly new to React Native, and I have been trying to make an event organizer where if you sign up for an event, it gets added to another page which contains your schedule. However, I have been looking through the documentation and I can't seem to find how you can send data from one screen to another without actually navigating to the other screen. In other words, I want this `navigation.navigate('Schedule', {name: eventName, time: eventTime});` but without navigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

**1. AsyncStorage:** You can save them to AsyncStorage (this is the hardware-backed secure storage on the phone) and they can be retrieved at any time. Let's say the user's schedule is an array of those events such as:

> ```
> var a = [{ name: eventName, time: eventTime }, { name: eventName, time: eventTime }]
> ```

You can do this:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('Schedule', JSON.stringify(a));
AsyncStorage.getItem('Schedule');
```

See: https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage

**2. Backend**

Save the events to your backend server and retrieve them from the other page.

**3. Redux or React Hooks (Advanced)**
https://medium.com/swlh/react-global-state-with-hooks-f163e49f90f9
https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started/

**4. Global State w/React Hooks**

[My new favorite way to manage global state with built-in React Hooks](https://medium.com/fullstacked/create-a-global-state-with-react-context-564524fc3b6c#218c)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global object to store your shared data between screens. even if you read `Redux` docs, one of the redux usage cases is when you have some data to share between different screens.

so here is the code for a global object (Singleton pattern)

```
export class GlobalState {
  public static getInstance(): GlobalState {
    if (GlobalState.instance == null) {
      GlobalState.instance = new GlobalState()
    }
    return GlobalState.instance
  }
private state: IGlobalState = this.restoreDefaultState()
private restoreDefaultState(): IGlobalState {
    return (
      {
        // your properties are placed here
      }
    )
  }
}
```

usage:

```
GlobalState.getInstance() ... //call any function placed there
```

Note: code above is writtent in `TypeScript`, you can easily convert it to `JS`.